# Visible seams on the mesh

Tags: modeling, uv, normals

This mesh has a seam on it.

When I apply texture on it the seam is visible.

How to fix this issue?

I also share the file

[image]

[image: seam problem]

Comment: Go into edit mode > Select All > Right click > Merge > By distance

Comment: @Gorgious please write an answer so this Q doesn't stay on the unanswered list :)

Comment: Done !  Pretty sure it is a dupe but my talents of archaeologist are quite limited it seems ;)

Answer (score 2):

Go into edit mode > Select All with <kbd>A</kbd> > Right click > Merge > By distance.